# Can't hard reset samsung and forgot the Pattern

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, pattern-lock, hard-reset

I have Samsung Galaxy Duos Grand Prime plus running Lollipop. I forgot the pattern.

- If I keep entering wrong pattern, the phone won't prompt me to enter
  the backup pin
- Volume up + home + power isn't working, the phone will boot normally. Volume up+ power isn't working either.
- Volume down + home + power takes me to the `downloading updates` screen and it get stuck there forever.

What other possible ways are there to remove the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, I need to draw 5 wrong patterns, before the phone asks for the pin code. But I noticed, that pattern consisting of few points (I think less than 4 points) do not count.

I hope this observation helps you. You need to draw 5 **complex** patterns (four or more points) in order to be asked for the pin.

Comment: If I do that, the phone will not let me any pattern for an hour, I can't force it to show the pin

Comment: Wow, one hour? On mine I'm blocked only for 30 seconds. Sorry, I can't help you further.